# Default Manager in Django

Tags: django, django-models

When I do not define any managers, I get no errors. However, when I do the following:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # some fields
    objects = model.Manager()
    hstore_manager = hstore.HStoreManager()
```

I get

```
AttributeError at'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

There is something wrong with /django/contrib/auth/backends.py in authenticate method on this line:

```
user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
```

Note that User is inherited from AbstractUser model. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication framework expects that the default manager on your `User` object implements some extra methods. The basic methods are implemented in `django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager`, the model-specific methods are implemented in `django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager`. If your user model is similar to the default implementation (that is, it defines the `username`, `email`, `is_staff`, `is_active`, `is_superuser`, `last_login`, and `date_joined` fields), you can just use the `UserManager`. Otherwise, you'll have to create a subclass of `BaseUserManager`, and implement the `create_user` and `create_superuser` methods.

As you are using `AbstractUser` as a base class, you can use the `UserManager` class, or if you need to define any additional methods, a subclass of `UserManager`.

Also read the documentation on [custom user managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager).

Comment: I also use custom User model and subclass it from AbstractUser. I need additional custom Managers so I subclassed custom manager from UserManager and it seems working.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you directly subclass from AbstructUser, you get this error. If you make one to one relation with user, then you will not get this error. For example:

```
class ExManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ExManager, self).get_queryset().all()

class Post(models.Model):
       user= models.OneToOneField(User)
       title= models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, default=None)
       objects=models.Manager()
       ab_ob= ExManager()
```

and in django shell I have tested:

```
In [2]: k=Post.ab_ob.all()
In [3]: k
Out[3]: []
In [4]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
In [5]: u=User.objects.get(id=1)
In [6]: k1=Post(user=u, title="asdasd")             
In [7]: k1.save()
In [8]: k2=Post.ab_ob.all()                         
In [9]: k2
Out[9]: [<Post: Post object>]
```